# Reporting the bad Ads

Tags: support

SE is testing new Ads provider: [We're testing advertisements across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network)

During the test period, some of us with no ad blocker may encounter some not appropriate ads. Here is a post to collect them all.

---

[ Question link. ]
[ Ads link or Screen shoot]

Animated : Yes / No
NSFW : Yes / No
Malicious (Scam) : Yes / No
Etc..

List of reason : why you believe it's bad if further information is needed

Comment: Fell free to edit the template or the question. To make it better.

Comment: How are the guys at MSE know about this feedback? There is currently no way to provide that feedback back to them. I applaud your idea of gathering the adds here, but we should also contemplate *how* is this feedback going to be useful. Browsing a bit I found this post which is requesting such feature to be able to submit feedback from ads:[Please give us an easy way to flag inappropriate ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329700/please-give-us-an-easy-way-to-flag-inappropriate-ads)

Comment: Several bad ads are recorded on the original post too.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, There is a lots of report on the SE question. But I feel like good site like Workplace should have their own report. I do update my answer on The main question too.

Comment: At the risk of sounding like I don't appreciate your initiative, I have found the sad truth to be that the vast majority of adds are animated. I just went and page-refreshed a bunch of questions and saw 8 adds. All 8 of them were animated. If "no animation" is one of the criteria for this trial, it's failure should be so obvious that we (users) don't need to put effort into reporting it.

Comment: @dwizum, My initiative is simple. Let people from XYZ Site that there is NSFW or inapropriate ads on their site. Most users brose with adblock and don't even know that we were testing add.The "tag" animated and Nsfw is just there because thats what I remember from reading answers on the main question.

Comment: @null I meant the original meta post here on Workplace.  I just edited my answer there last week to add a new sighting of a bad ad.  That's the post I meant, sorry.

Comment: Somebody reported one of our inappropriate ads directly on main meta and it got a response within hours saying that ad would be taken down.  Looks like that's the place to get attention and not here at all, whether on this post or the original.  Thanks for bringing this up here (I definitely agree that ad is NSFW); might need to post there?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I also got the same answer from the same staff 7 days ago. And it was on a site meta. But the ads are still here. I guess it's the 6-9 weeks or the lake of twitter. Edit: Weight lost ads are gone, in my daily few click with out adblock routine.

Answer (score 5):

### *Warning:* The following ads maybe : Animated, NSFW.

1. 2019 09 17:

> [image]

with animation here https://sgreen.erne.co/creatives?id=Qz0vFA1iZriUIOLHhxqE

2. 2019 09 18:

> [image]

with animation here https://sgreen.erne.co/creatives?id=SqKf2HoBhvvuQTmWIPn4

Answer (score 2):

Animated low content click baits. Could be fraudulent. Workplace, 2019 09 20

SFW but low quality.

Example in situation

> [image]

Links to animated versions

https://sgreen.erne.co/creatives?id=z8RLIEknelrKmHVpqkZ2

https://sgreen.erne.co/creatives?id=zE6j1Zaut3orDdFgkcZX

Suggestion by gnat to automate these exchanges https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329782/530922